# Copy only few folders with complete structure with rsync

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to copy a list of folders with its complete data structure to target.

I have 20 folders in source, but I want to copy just 7 from them with their files and sub-folders. I've tried to use the option `--files-from=FILE.txt` option; it copies the folders I've mentioned but it's not copying the subfolder files and directories.

Any one have experienced the same?

Comment: Please provide the complete command-line including all options you called `rsync` with so we can help you find the reason for the unwanted behaviour.

Comment: We could either use `--exclude`, excluding portions of the source directory tree, or instead specifically rsync those 7 folders you want to sync.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the problem strongly depends on *which* options you actually called `rsync` with.

Note, however that if you specify `--files-from`, then you explicitly have to add the `-r` flag to recursively copy directory and subdirectory contents, because `--files-from` changes the default behaviour of *rsync* (in particular that of the `-a` option, which under normal circumstances implies `-r`).